# Writing to the folder where executable is located

Tags: windows, security

I have a program and a windows service located in the same folder. They could be run under different user accounts. Will they be always able to write to the folder where their .exe are located or this still depends on the rights of a particular account they run under? If not then what folder can I use for sharing common data amoung them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In general, executables are installed in `\Program Files\` (`CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES`). You need a program-specific subdirectory under `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`. (Create this subdirectory with appropriate ACL's for your situation).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases (i.e. for most kinds of accounts which are not Administrators) the application (or the service) won't be able to write to \Program Files folder if it has been installed there (as it's done by default).

To share the data between applications you can use [FOLDERID_ProgramData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) folder and get it's path using [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).